# I am trying to get total interest for certain period

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code that I am using to calculate the total interest for invested amount over 1 month or 2 month or 3 months. The interest rate is 1.2% daily. What it's currently doing now is it calculates the interest but it does not compound. I want it to calculate the interest for the day and on the following day it must start counting from the previous total.

For instance if a user is investing $30 dollars with 1.2% interest daily for 1 month. On the first day it will be $30,36 and on the second it will be 30,72...etc but now it's counting using the same amount.

Can someone please assist.

```
 var totalI = 0;
 var i;

 for( i=0; i< period; i++){

    totalI +=   0.012 * amount; 

 }
```

Comment: You need to factor `i` into the equation.

Comment: you need to `compound` ... currently, amount is the same in every iteration - however, rather than using a loop, there is a formula for compounding interest

Comment: So, you want to add interest daily, but how often should it compound? daily? `const interest = (P, r, t) => P * (Math.pow( 1 + r, t) - 1);` ... `interest(30, 0.012, 30)` == `12.9078.....` interest after 30 days

Comment: alternatively `const A = (P, r, t) => P * Math.pow( 1 + r, t);` and `A(30, 0.012, 30)` will give you the balance after 30 days - which, of course, is `42.9078.....`

Comment: Thank you Jaromanda X. You are a legend. It worked!

Comment: it worked, but did it help you understand why your code _didn't_ ?   You were only missing one simple term.

Answer (score 0):

The interest paid each day is calculated based on the initial amount invested *plus* the interest accumulated so far:

```
const amount = 30.00;
const rate = 0.012;
const periods = 30;

let totalI = 0.0;
for (let i = 0; i < periods; ++i) {
    let interest = rate * (amount + totalI);
    totalI += interest;
}
```